# How to create an icon shortcut with NSIS?

Tags: jar, nsis

I'd like to create an icon-shortcut for my jar file with NSIS 
I've tried so, but after it doesn't display the icon I would to change.

```
; Shortcuts
!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_BEGIN Application
 CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\Brio Gate.lnk" "$INSTDIR\BrioGate.jar" "..\..\Users\Foo\Desktop\ico.ico,0"
!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_END
SectionEnd
```

Where do I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If BrioGate.jar is an application you want to start, this is not the best way to do it. Clicking that shortcut on my machine would open the .jar in winrar!

Answer (score 22):

You should really provide the full path and the path and index are two separate [parameters](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.3.4), also, skipped parameters must be empty, you cannot just leave them out:

```
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\Brio Gate.lnk" "$INSTDIR\BrioGate.jar" "" "$INSTDIR\myicon.ico" 0
```